# Is it possible to use asp-for to a contenteditable div element?

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `contenteditable=true` div element to enter html input text. It is a required field. Can I use `asp-for` attribute for this element?

```
<div asp-for="Comment" contenteditable="true"></div>
<span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Appreciate any comments

Comment: Short answer is no. And it would make no sense anyway since a `<div>` does not post back a value

Answer (score 1):

The `contenteditable` attribute does not magically make a random element a form field. You'd need to use JS to either track changes and update an input/textarea (which you'd add `asp-for` to) or use JS to post the div contents via AJAX.